# Prettyfaces and the container based security

Tags: java, prettyfaces

I have problem using the container-based security with prettyfaces. As far as I disable prettyfaces (remove its existence in pom.xml), the container-based security is working fine and pages are secured well.
However, with using prettyfaces, the security is not working anymore and the secured pages can be accessed without authentication (i am not applying pretty-faces filter on the secured pages). Even when I am using the empty pretty-config.xml (the only).

i am using Jboss AS

**Edit:**

With this setup, pages /user/* are accessed without the need of authentication. After removing the prettyfaces from pom.xml it works well.

part of the web.xml:

```
   <security-role>
    <description>Users</description>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
   </security-role>

   <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>General use.</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login-fail.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

prettyfaces-config.xml (when using empty pretty-config.xml):

```
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces
                  http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/rewrite-config-prettyfaces.xsd">


</pretty-config>
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of your configuration?

Comment: Added web.xml and prettyfaces-config.xml. I hope its enough

Comment: Are you using PrettyFaces annotations? How are you defining your page mappings?

Comment: I am using only xml, no annotations/classes. However, I am having problems even if the pretty-config is empty (e.g just after creating prettyfaces-config.xml + adding prettyfaces to pom.xml the security stops working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: As it happens, this was a bug in Rewrite that is fixed in version 2.0.4.Final. (See related forum post - http://ocpsoft.org/support/topic/prettyfaces-with-container-based-security/ )

Comment: Hi, thank you for the interest.I gave an example when I am not using any of the prettyfaces mapping but it still fails. I have tried several simple applications and I was following these steps: 1.create application. 2. create web.xml and add the security constraint that is mentioned in the edited version. 3. Create simple login.xhtml, login-fail.xhtml and user/secured.xhtml .  Now it works fine... Now just adding prettyfaces to pom.xml (2.0.1.Final exactly copied 2 dependencies for JSF2 from "http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/ ").. Nothing more. After build/clean it fails (even on glassfish).

Comment: Could you create a topic on the OCPsoft support forums and upload your sample project sources, including POM, .java, and any configuration files? I think I need to take a closer look at this.

Comment: I created a topic on the OCPsoft.

Comment: Ok great, thanks. Sorry I have been a bit busy, I will look at it soon.

Comment: Hi, thank you, it is working now. Can you edit or create a new answer with the fixed version so I can mark it as accepted for others?

Comment: Done! Thanks for the reminder. And thanks again for finding and reporting this issue. OSS ftw!